# improving efficiency of algorithm for generating minHeaps over some interval

Tags: algorithm, heap

For a given natural number n, for generating all of the min heaps for example for n=4, total heaps are 3, For a bigger value of n the limited heaps should be generated like 20-30 over reasonable interva

1. 1 2 3 4
2. 1 2 4 3
3. 1 3 2 4

   I came up with the following idea to generate all heaps.
   start with a loop in i from 1 to n and push i to a vector also mark it as used. Now recurse in the function and if marked continue, so in case of adding i if the parent is already greater then continue with next value as this will make an invalid heap. Please refer to below code, I think I did a terrible job explaining that. The problem is it takes too much time for n=16 or n=17. I tried to optimise it by reducing computation where the first element of the vector was anything other than 1.

I would like to have suggestions for improving its efficiency or any other algorithms to effectively generate all min Heaps.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> v;
int n,k ;
int cnt = 0 ;
vector<int> p(100,0);

void gen(){
    if(v.size() == n){
        cnt++;
        if(cnt % k == 0){
            for(auto x : v){
                cout<<x<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    else{
        
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++){
            
            if(v.size() and v[0] != 1 ){
                return ;
            }
            if(p[i])
                continue;
            
            
            int x = v.size();
            int parent ;
            if(x & 1){
                parent = (x-1)/2;
            }
            else
                parent = (x-2)/2;
                
            if(x==0)
                parent = 0 ; 
            
            if(v.size() and v[parent] > i ){
                continue ;
            }
            
            
            p[i] = 1;
            v.push_back(i);
            gen();
            p[i] = 0;
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(NULL);
    cin>>n>>k;
    gen();
    cout<<"TOTAL "<<cnt<<endl;
    
}
```

Comment: The output size is exponential in the input. Do you really want to generate all of them, or just count number of them? Also what is your min-heap format? Left-skewed binary tree?

Comment: I want to generate them

Comment: What's the current performance of the code? (for example, for `n=15`, what's the number of generated min-heap, and how long does your code take to generate them?) ([edit] your question to add more information)

Comment: I generate them occasionally, meaning printing over some interval

Comment: for n=16 this procedure take 36 sec to count and print like 20 or 30 of them

Comment: for n=16 we have 108108000 heaps

Comment: I think that printing 108108000 heaps in 36 seconds, although not the fastest, is reasonable. What do you expect?

Comment: as I said we need to print some of them like 20-30 over reasonable intervals not all of them

Comment: Then [edit] your question to describe your actual problem. You want to print min-heaps in a small interval of permutations, specify that in the question.

Comment: Also edit your current code and question body.

Comment: now it does, please check

Comment: Do you really want to generate min-heaps at indices divisible by `k`, or just 10-20 random min-heaps?

Comment: k can be very large, not random over some interval

Comment: do you have any  suggestions for improvement

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with heaps of 10 or more items, one easy way that might work very well is to randomize an array and then use the `build-heap` function to turn it into a heap. Lather, rinse, repeat.

You'll have to check each time to see if the new heap matches any of the existing heaps, but if you're only generating 20 or 30 heaps, that's not going to be a huge performance problem.

I'll grant that this solution isn't the most efficient, but it should get the job done reasonably quickly.

For reference, the `build-heap` function:

```
for (int i = v.size/2; i >= 0; --i)
{
    siftDown(i);
}
```